# Commentaries on aruch hashulchan

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, commentaries, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, aruch-hashulchan

Did anyone write a peirush on aruch hashulchan?(on the choshen mishpat part) I am looking for a english or hebrew commentary.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have on Choshen Mishpat: http://www.aron-hasfarim.co.il/product.asp?productid=1959